# Netty server buffer read multiple messages at once

Tags: java, netty, nio

#### 1. Current problem

- 1 Netty client, 1 Netty server
- In netty client, **3 different kafka threads** send message to netty server by **1 ChannelHandler**
- On netty client side, it seems like channel handler send each thread's message at once.
  But on netty server side, it seems like netty read multiple messages sent from 3 kafka threads at once.
- I checked this by logging :
  [Client side log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc9xy.png), [Server side log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30PQu.png)

#### 2. Code

Netty client code

```java
public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        log.debug("channelActive");
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        log.info("Sent message: {}", message);
        ByteBuf messageBuffer = Unpooled.buffer();
        messageBuffer.writeBytes(message.getBytes());
        ctx.writeAndFlush(messageBuffer);
    }
```

Netty server code

```java
public class NettyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        NettyServer.ServerStatus.increaseAndGetTotalReadMsg();
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf)msg;
        log.info(byteBuf.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
        byteBuf.release();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907416/netty-concurrent-writeandflush) says that `writeAndFlush` is thread-safe but it seem's doesn't. Is it normal case or not?

Comment: I am confused why you think `writeAndFlush` is not thread-safe... As this is TCP there is no guarantee on how many bytes you will read at once.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @NormanMaurer . You pointed out that I wasn't clearly know how TCP works. Now I know that it's not the matter of concurrency and it's perfectly normal. Thank you for your help!